# Relation between two list ? [SharePoint 2010]

Tags: list, sharepoint-2010

Do you know how to do a relationship between two lists in SharePoint? I'd like to get an effect similar to the tables in the relation database. So having two lists:  ListA and ListB, connect them after IDName relationship. I would like to add a ListA button opening ListB and I will be able to add the address of the person. 
I'm waiting for yours ideas, how to do this ?
Sorry for my english.

Thanks,
Lukasz

```
ListA:

**IDName** Name Telephone

ListB

IDAdress **IDName**  Street Country
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using a lookup column on ListA the points to a column in ListB?

If you want to show the full address in the lookup, you can create a calculated column in ListB to concatenate whatever columns you need and do the lookup on the calculated column.

I think this is the nearest you will get to a proper relationship.

Comment: Check the *additional fields* feature introduced in SharePoint 2010: http://weblogs.asp.net/bsimser/archive/2009/10/19/sp2010-what-s-new-lookup-columns-spc09.aspx

Comment: Yes, I tried. But I want to create new item from ListB using ListA only. You can imagine, list form, you add value and click button on this list and open ListB , create relation when add value to ListB.

Comment: I think I understand what you are trying to do. I think it would be worth looking at this JQuery addon library that will do what you are asking. http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=$().SPServices.SPLookupAddNew&referringTitle=Documentation

Comment: Hi Andy, thanks for your replay. SPLookUpNew is probably what I want, but I don't know Jquery ;(, mayby you have some idea how to do this not using JQuery or give me some example Jquery for start. Thanks